# SQL to find multiple occurence of a substring in a column of type varchar and its value

Tags: sql, json, amazon-athena, presto, trino

I am using Athena as database tables. I want to parse a column called 'line_items' in table orders. So each row in orders table consist of a customer order and line_items contain details of all the products included in the customer order. I want to find the product_id of each item in line_items and then based on these product_id, I need to join each product_id with its details in product_details table.

The data type of line_items is varchar, and it cannot be changed.

The sample value of one of the order is as follows:

```
   [{'id': 13942775087176, 'admin_graphql_api_id': 'gid://shop/LineItem/13942775087176', 'fulfillable_quantity': 0, 'fulfillment_service': 'manual', 'fulfillment_status': 'fulfilled', 'gift_card': False, 'grams': 585, 'name': 'Military Green Comfort Chino Pants - 36', 'pre_tax_price': 44.89, 'pre_tax_price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': '44.89', 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': '44.89', 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'price': 44.89, 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': 44.89, 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': 44.89, 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'product_exists': True, 'product_id': 6633367306312, 'properties': [{'name': '_igTestGroups', 'value': 'fee1aa1f534b,71aca8e2923f'}, {'name': '_igTestGroup', 'value': '33c7ca5a-faf4-452e-adba-fee1aa1f534b'}], 'quantity': 1, 'requires_shipping': True, 'sku': 'TCT4702MGRN36', 'tax_code': 'PC040100', 'taxable': True, 'title': 'Military Green Comfort Chino Pants', 'total_discount': 0.0, 'total_discount_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': 0.0, 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': 0.0, 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'variant_id': 39507850657864, 'variant_inventory_management': 'shop', 'variant_title': '36', 'vendor': 'True Classic', 'tax_lines': [{'channel_liable': False, 'price': 2.51, 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': 2.51, 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': 2.51, 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'rate': 0.056, 'title': 'AZ STATE TAX'}, {'channel_liable': False, 'price': 0.31, 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': 0.31, 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': 0.31, 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'rate': 0.007, 'title': 'AZ COUNTY TAX'}, {'channel_liable': False, 'price': 1.03, 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': 1.03, 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': 1.03, 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'rate': 0.023, 'title': 'AZ CITY TAX'}], 'duties': [], 'discount_allocations': []}, {'id': 13942775119944, 'admin_graphql_api_id': 'gid://shop/LineItem/13942775119944', 'fulfillable_quantity': 0, 'fulfillment_service': 'manual', 'fulfillment_status': 'fulfilled', 'gift_card': False, 'grams': 585, 'name': 'Khaki Comfort Chino Pants - 36', 'pre_tax_price': 44.89, 'pre_tax_price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': '44.89', 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': '44.89', 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'price': 44.89, 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': 44.89, 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': 44.89, 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'product_exists': True, 'product_id': 6633366388808, 'properties': [{'name': '_igTestGroups', 'value': 'fee1aa1f534b,71aca8e2923f'}, {'name': '_igTestGroup', 'value': '33c7ca5a-faf4-452e-adba-fee1aa1f534b'}], 'quantity': 1, 'requires_shipping': True, 'sku': 'TCT4702KHAKI36', 'tax_code': 'PC040100', 'taxable': True, 'title': 'Khaki Comfort Chino Pants', 'total_discount': 0.0, 'total_discount_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': 0.0, 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': 0.0, 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'variant_id': 39507846725704, 'variant_inventory_management': 'shop', 'variant_title': '36', 'vendor': 'True Classic', 'tax_lines': [{'channel_liable': False, 'price': 2.51, 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': 2.51, 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': 2.51, 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'rate': 0.056, 'title': 'AZ STATE TAX'}, {'channel_liable': False, 'price': 0.31, 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': 0.31, 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': 0.31, 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'rate': 0.007, 'title': 'AZ COUNTY TAX'}, {'channel_liable': False, 'price': 1.03, 'price_set': {'shop_money': {'amount': 1.03, 'currency_code': 'USD'}, 'presentment_money': {'amount': 1.03, 'currency_code': 'USD'}}, 'rate': 0.023, 'title': 'AZ CITY TAX'}], 'duties': [], 'discount_allocations': []}]
```

I wrote a query which returns me id of first line_item, but I need all the ids in the line_items. How can I find the SQL solution for this?

Query written by me:

```
select split_part(SUBSTRING(line_items, posa + 6, 20), ',', 1) as line_item_id from (
 select POSITION('''id'': ' IN line_items) as posa, substring(line_items, POSITION('''id'': ' IN line_items)+6, POSITION(',' IN line_items)) AS id_value, line_items
 from orders where id in ('45245','5463556','64874')
 )
```

Output of my query is:

```
13942775087176
```

I want id of each line-item and then later on, also need to do summation of amount field in the line_items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is JSON so you can process as JSON by parsing, casting to array of JSON and then using unnest:

```
-- sample data
with dataset(line_items) as (
    values (your_json_str_from_post)
)

-- query
select json_extract_scalar(m, '$.id') product_id,
       json_extract_scalar(m, '$.quantity') quantity
from dataset,
    unnest(cast(json_parse(line_items) as array(json))) as t(m);
```

Output:

| product_id | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 13942775087176 | 1 |
| 13942775119944 | 1 |

Comment: So I tried your solution as -- sample data
with dataset as (
    select line_items from 
        orders where id = '4245'
    )

-- query
select json_extract_scalar(m, '$.id') product_id,
       json_extract_scalar(m, '$.quantity') quantity
from dataset,
    unnest(cast(json_parse(line_items) as array(json))) as t(m) ; But it is giving error as INVALID_CAST_ARGUMENT: Cannot cast to array(json).

Comment: please refer above comment.

Comment: ok I made certain changes and it seems to be working. with dataset as (
    select replace(replace(replace(line_items, 'True', 'true'), 'False', 'false'), '''', '"') as line_items from 
        orders where id = '4245'
    )
    

-- query
select json_extract_scalar(m, '$.id') product_id,
       json_extract_scalar(m, '$.quantity') quantity
from dataset,
    unnest(cast(json_parse(line_items) as array(json))) as t(m)

Comment: @azaveri7 sorry, only now seen the comments. Was glad to help! And glad that you have figured out the difference (I have used online JSON formatter on the original string, so it maybe fixed the tokens).